# printing nodes from a singly-linked list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I made a node class which is a linked list class. Is there any way I can print out elements in this list ? I made my `print()` method but it only returns the first element which is 21. How do I iterate through that list ?

```
public class ListNode {
    private int item;
    private ListNode next;

    public ListNode(int item, ListNode next){
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public ListNode(int item){
        this(item, null);
    }

    public int print(){
        return item;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        ListNode list = new ListNode(21, new ListNode(5, new ListNode(19, null)));
        System.out.println(list.print());
    }
```

}

Comment: Your `print()` method is misleading - given the current implementation, it should be called `getValue()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public String toString() {
    String result = item + " ";
    if (next != null) {
        result += next.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then you can simply do

```
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

(I renamed your function from `print` to `toString` to give a more accurate description of what it does)

Comment: @Dima: Sorry, reverted your edit, I think what you say is right, but you would also have to add this explanation to the answer, otherwise it becomes more difficult to understand compared to its current state.

Answer (score 1):

Your current implementation doesn't print anything: it simply returns item.
More appropriate implementation would look like:

```
public void print() {
    System.out.println(item); 
}
```

You can then use recursion to print all items:

```
public void printAll() {
    print();
    if (next != null) {
        System.out.println("; ");
        next.printAll(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a `printall`

```
public void printAll(){
    System.out.println(item);
    if (next != null){
        next.printAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `print()` function is returning only a single item that's why it is printing only 21.

Call recursively to print all the values until `next != NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `list.print()` will only ever return the value of the head (21) - you are never making any reference or call to the next node: `next`.

Personally, I would remove the print() method and instead override toString():

```
@override
public String toString(){
    return item + "\n" + next;
}
```

I guess you probably don't want the null tail printed, so this is probably nicer:

```
@override
public String toString(){
    if(next) {
        return item + "\n" + next;
    } else {
        return item + "\n";
    }
}
```

Then in, main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
    ListNode list = new ListNode(21, new ListNode(5, new ListNode(19, null)));
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop:

```
List<ListNode> theList = new LinkedList<ListNode>();
//add stuff to the list
for(ListNode n:theList)
   System.out.println(n.print();
```

THis will iterate over the list and return the next object, on this object we call the `print()` method

Answer (score 0):

Convert list into an array `var arr = list.toArray();` after that print the array  `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));`

```
public int[] toArray(){
    int [] arry = new int[size];
    var current = first;
    var index = 0;

        while (current!=null){
            arry[index++] = current.value;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return arry;
    }
```