# java code, no output after compile

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

when i compile this java code, i got blank (nothing in the output).
why the output is blank ? whats the problem in the code ?
the code as you see is about Linkedlist.
I tried a lot of ways with no success, seems like theres something i am not aware of.
I really appreciate your help.
thanks.

```
public class Node {

private String data;
private Node next;

public Node (String data, Node next)
{
    this.data=data;
    this.next=next;
}

public String getData()
{
    return data;
}

public Node getNext()
{
    return next;
}

public void setData(String s)
{
    data=s;
}

public void setNext(Node n)
{
    next=n;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Node [data=" + data + ", next=" + next + "]";
}


public static void main(String[] args) {


//      Node cNode = new Node ("c",null);
//      Node bNode = new Node ("b",cNode);
//      Node list = new Node ("a",bNode);


        Node list = new Node ("A", new Node("B",new Node("C",null)));



            getThird(list);
            insertSecond(list,"k");
            size(list);




    }

    //1st method
    public static String getThird(Node list)
    {
        return list.getNext().getNext().getData();      
    }

    //2nd method
    public static void insertSecond (Node list, String s)
    {
        Node newNode=new Node("s",null);
        newNode.setNext(list.getNext());
        list.setNext(newNode);
    }

    //3rd method
    public static int size(Node list)
    {
        int count=0;
        while(list!=null)
        {
            count++;
            list=list.getNext();
        }
        return count;
    }
```

}

Comment: What do you _think_ should be happening?

Comment: Add breakpoints and watch your variables

Comment: You're not printing anything.  That'd be the leading cause as to why there's no output.

Comment: I think you forgot about the actual outputting... Use `System.out.print` or print line to show output.

Comment: Print the return values.

Comment: You are also missing a `main` method.  So this code is not runnable.

Comment: @Brandon, no he's not. It's there. It just doesn't print anything.

Comment: @Brandon I think he didn't forgot to include the main method. He's not printing anything though.

Comment: the code runs without any error, doesn't the return supposed to print on the screen ?

Comment: @user102291 Print the result. Try this System.out.println(getThird(list));

Comment: ok thanks. i just thought the "return" in the method would print on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for this to print to your console you are going to need to print it out.

As posted already on Stackexchange... here [printing nodes from a singly-linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565045/printing-nodes-from-a-singly-linked-list)

You need to do this:

```
System.out.print(list.toString());
```

Comment: This doesn't need to be a comment. It answers the question. But, just for future reference, if you can't post a comment, you shouldn't try to find a way around it. You should just not post the comment.

Comment: ok thanks (solved). i just thought that "return" in the method would print on the screen

Comment: well now I can comment so I will not need to use a work around now :D